# AJAX is not parsing Data and not using PATCH method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am relatively new to Ajax, my problem is I am trying to submit the form as PATCH, and parse url, which is sent by Mustache `{{add_member_url}}`, I do not get any errors, and backend works, I have tried it. The server receives GET, although my form `method="PATCH"`, and Ajax `method="PATCH"`, there are two functions in Ajax first get - I render the form second is `PATCH` to submit the form.

JavaScript

```
$('.list').on('click', '#add', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var url_send = $(this).data("add_url")
        // $("#yourModal").modal({"backdrop": "static"});
        $.get(''+$(this).data("add_url"), function(data){
            console.log(this);
            var template = $("#add_member_template").html();
            console.log("T",template);
            data.add_member_url = url_send;
            console.log(data.add_member_url);
            var rendered = Mustache.render(template, data);
            console.log(rendered);
            $('.contain').html(rendered);

        });
    });



    $('.contain').on('submit', '#add_member', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        console.log('U',$(this).data("add_url"));
        $.ajax({
            url:''+$(this).data("add_url"),
            method: 'PATCH',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(method);

        }
        });


    });
});
```

HTML Form

```
<div id="forma" class="contain" ></div>
    <script id="add_member_template" type="mustache/template"> 

    <form id="theForm"  action="" method="PATCH">

            {% csrf_token %}
            {% verbatim %}

<p> {{pk}} </p>
<p><label for="ssn">SSN:</label>
<input id="ssn" type="text" name="tename"  data-add_url="{{add_member_url}}" value="{{tename}}"></p>

<button id="add_member" data-add_url="{{add_member_url}}" type="submit" value="save" class="btn blue">Submit</button>



            {% endverbatim %}
        </form>

        </script>
```

Comment: Why do you write `''+$(this).data("add_url")` instead of just `$(this).data("add_url")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event binding is wrong. The `submit` event only occurs on forms, not on the submit button. You need to bind to the button's `click` event:

```
$(".contain").on("click", "#add_member", function(event) {... });
```

Comment: I have change it, the problem is, it is not parsing the action url((

Comment: $('.contain').on('submit', '#theForm', function(event){event.preventDefault();
  
  console.log('U',$(this).data("add_url"));
  $.ajax({
      url:$('#theForm').attr('action'),
      method: 'PATCH',
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
       console.log(method);

     }
  });
  
  
 });

Comment: I changed my answer to remove that. `$(this).data("add_url")` only works when `this` is the button, not the form, because the form doesn't have that `data` attribute.

Comment: Barmar, it gets url with  (".contain").on("click", "#add_member", function(event) {... }); )))

Comment: But now it gives me an error ReferenceError: method is not defined

Comment: You never assigned the variable `method`. Did you mean `console.log(data)`?